# Performance comparison of list over map on simple iteration in C++

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

I have a list and a map . Each of them contains the same elements, just that in the map, it is indexed by an integer (i dont think that is relevant in this question).
If i do  a simple iteration from `container.begin()` to `container.end()` , would there be a difference in complexity between a list and a map? Would there be a difference in actual performance between list and map?

Comment: Create a benchmark and check?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The standard requires that iterators have amortized constant complexity for `operator++`, so there would be no difference in complexity.

There almost certainly would be a difference in actual time taken. It would be some coincidence (or an unusual implementation of `map`) if they were precisely the same. The difference might be small.